# WP function won't work on 404 template page

Tags: functions, 404-error, date-time

I made a custom template of error 404 page.
In my header.php i use the_time() function to display current date.
There is some problem with 404 page because the_time() function won't work, not return any date.
Why is that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`the_time` does not display the current date,** *it displays the date of the current post,* and 404 pages do not have a current post.

For this reason, if it ever returned a date on the 404 page then it would be a bug.

Instead you should use the PHP functions that come with PHP to display the current date and time.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't read about this function properly. I just copied it from the WP developers documentation site and paste into my code. :) My fail and mistake.